# Why does Azure AD (or other OIDC Idp) require to enter user credentials for sign-in after sign-out?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, owin, openid-connect, okta

I develop an authentication by extrenal idps in the my application. For while I support two idps using OpenId Connect protocol: Azure AD and Okta. My login page has widget for entering user's credentials (for built-in users and for domain users imported from Active Directory) and two buttons: "Login with Microsoft" and "Login with Okta".

First time user is redirected to login page and he attempts to sign in by Okta (or Azure AD). If he has already signed in Okta (or Azure AD) before attempt he will be signed in my app **autmatically** without entring his credentials (SSO in action). But if he signed out from my app, the next time he will try to sign in by Okta he will be redirected to Okta consent page and **required to enter his credentials**.

Why do second and next attempts require user's credentials but not lead to automatic sign in?
Is this SSO concept?
I develop on Asp.net MVC and use OWIN (Katana).
Thanks!

Comment: How are you handling the logout action?

Comment: @JanHudec I clear client-server and app-idp cookies.
    
                      HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(AuthTypes.Okta, AuthTypes.Cookies);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely reason the user is signed out of the identity provider is that your code is intentionally doing that when you call `SignOut`.

For example, if you are calling:

```cs
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(AuthTypes.Okta, AuthTypes.Cookies);
```

You are explicitly saying that you want to trigger sign-out for `AuthTypes.Cookies` (which probably clears your app's own session cookies) and `AuthTypes.Okta` (which probably includes redirecting to Okta to end the session and clear cookies over there as well).

If you only want to end the session with your app (but not necessarily end the user's session with the identity provider), when you call `SignOut`, you should only indicate your app's authentication types:

```cs
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(AuthTypes.Cookies);
```

After this, when the user accesses the app again, the app will not consider the user signed in (because when the user's browser accesses the app, it will not be presenting any session cookies). However, if the user were to be sent off to Okta or Azure AD again, the identity provider's own session cookies for that user will still be there, and they will be able to SSO with no extra prompts.

*Note: I'm making a few assumptions about how `AuthTypes.Okta` and `AuthTypes.Cookies` are configured, since that wasn't included in the question.*

Comment: thank you for reply!
When I do sign-out I clear Idp cookies. But when were cookies created? I have thought cookies were created after user's first sign-in my app but now I think cookies were created after user's login in AzureAD/Okta/Google and when user tries to sign into my app first time these cookies provides SSO (user is not required to enter credentials), is it right?

Comment: Most identity providers will maintain a sign-in session for a user by setting session cookies when the user signs in. If the identity provider supports "single sign out", when that is triggered (often via a redirect to the identity provider's logout URL), these session cookies are removed or made invalid, so that if the user is sent back to the identity provider later, the user is not recognized as being signed in and is prompted to sign in again.